# How to trigger an event when Asp.Net MVC Model is created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have and OrderModel and that has a bunch of Date Properties. I would like to trigger an event when when the DateSubmitted property is set for a newly created Order, or in this case just when a new OrderModel is created.

So my model I have the following

```
        public DateTime? DateSubmitted
        {
          get
          {
            return this.dateSubmitted;   
           }
          set
          {
            this.dateSubmitted = value;
            var args = new StatusChangedEventArgs();
            args.NewDate = value;
            this.OrderSubmitted(this, args);
          }
        }
```

In the controller I have something like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(OrderModel order, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        order.DateSubmitted = System.DateTime.Now;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("MyOrders");
    }
```

But when I set a break point in the controller and walk through the code it never hits the set action of the DateSubmittedProperty and thus the event is never raised.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In Visual Studio go to the Debug options and uncheck `Step over properties and operators (Managed Only)` Than step through the code using F11.

Comment: Thanks. By Changing those options I could see that the event was being raised when a new order was created and the DateSubmitted Property was set. The problem was with the code the event was executing.